# How to pass several parameters as a list into a JDBC template

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

this is an example:

```
public int addEmplyee(int id) {
    return jdbcTemplate.update(
      "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", id, "Bill", "Gates", "USA");
}
```

If instead of passing `id`, `"Bill"`, `"Gates"` and `"USA"` as a parameter, I want to store them in a list and want to pass it that way, how can I do it?

Comment: You shouldn't ideally be doing this, since not all parameters are the same type (the first is an integer, the last three are strings).

Comment: you can check overloaded method https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-

Comment: @SachinTiwari can we do the same for `JdbcTemplate.queryForList` ?

Answer (score 1):

[`update()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) takes a vararg (`Object...`) as argument. This is just syntactic sugar for an array. So you can just pass an array as argument:

```
return jdbcTemplate.update(
  "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", new Object[] {id, "Bill", "Gates", "USA"});
```

If you jave a List, then simply [transform it to an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--).